# AWS Glue Development Endpoint Not Working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark, aws-lake-formation

I am trying to use a development Endpoint to interactively run and edit ETL scripts but there seems to some issues in the development endpoint just after creating it as i am getting errors in scala/python REPL and also unable to do SSH tunnel to remote interpreter.
Let me explain what i did exactly - I created a development endpoint in the AWS console with all the default configurations. While creating the development endpoint i only provided three things 'Development endpoint name' and 'IAM Role' and my 'pub ssh key'. This is how it looks after creation

[image]

Then Right After creating the endpoint i am connecting to the spark/python REPL, I am able to connect to them successfully but within couple of minutes of connecting, the REPL starts throwing errors without writing a single line of code. This is happening in all the REPL present in the development endpoints.

[image]

Also When I am trying to do SSH tunneling to remote interpreter to connect my Local Zeppelin Notebook it is throwing - "bind: Cannot assign requested address".

Couple of things that are working though -

- Able to do ssh to the endpoint.
- Created a Sagemaker notebook in the AWS glue that is attached to this development endpoint and this notebook seems to be working fine, although surely it is adding an additional cost and i don't want to continue using it.

Can anyone please help what am i doing wrong? Am I missing any important steps that is needed to be done on the machine right after creating the development endpoint?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: were you able to figure this out? My team is facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure about this error but if you are using it smaller datasets then probably you would like to use Docker implementation as it will not add any additional cost and you can go on with your developments.

You can refer this blog on how to set it up

https://towardsdatascience.com/develop-glue-jobs-locally-using-docker-containers-bffc9d95bd1